# How to know whether user has changed the state of toggle button?

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have ten toggle buttons. I want to save the state of five of those buttons when clicking the home button. But I want to save it only if the user has made a change to any of the buttons' state. Is there any way to know the change in states without using setOnClickListener()?

Answer (score 35):

I have done the following, its not so nice, but it works:

```
ttsButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.solution_ttsbutton);
ttsButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleButtonChangeListener);
...
// gets called, if the button state changes
final CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener toggleButtonChangeListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // The user changed the button, do something
    }
};
```

and I do the following, if I want to change the button programatically without executing the change listener:

```
ttsButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
ttsButton.setChecked(false);
ttsButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleButtonChangeListener);
```

Comment: Cleaner example and description here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Answer (score 22):

There is a simple way to know if user clicks the CompoundButton (CheckBox, Switch, RadioButton, ToggleButton), use the following:

```
 new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
            if (compoundButton.isPressed()) {
                // do something related to user click/tap
            } else {
                // do something related to programmatically state changes (checked/unchecked)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer unless somebody can prove that that `.isPressed()` doesn't toggle for other input devices like a stylus (but I doubt that)

Comment: This answer is correct! I checked several test cases and it worked!

Answer (score 15):

Use `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` class.

```
ToggleButton button = /* ... */;
button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // Save the state here
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: If you want to use a single listener:

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener =
        new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        String key = null;
        switch(buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                key = "key1";
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                key = "key2";
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        // Save the state here using key
    }
});

ToggleButton button1 = /* ... */;    
button1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);

ToggleButton button2 = /* ... */;
button2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```

But there're plenty of ways to implement this really. So you can make up another method which suits your need better then this one.

Comment: How can I use a single listner for all the toggle buttons?

Comment: As I see this does not answer the question. A more precise formulation would be: How to differentiate between button.setChecked(); and a user click? onCheckedChanged gets called in both cases.

Comment: And as I can see from the question, the author is not interested in differentiating between a user action and a method call and just wants to know when states of the buttons are changed.

Comment: I get a different *id* from the button checked !, `.getId()` does not return the expected *id* !

Answer (score 3):

**Use a custom view**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.Switch;

public class CustomSwitch extends Switch {


    private OnCheckedChangeListener mListener;

    public CustomSwitch(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        // Do not call supper method
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        super.setChecked(checked);

        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onCheckedChanged(this, checked);
        }
    }

    public void setCheckedProgrammatically(boolean checked) {
        // You can call super method, it doesn't have a listener... he he :)
        super.setChecked(checked);
    }

}
```

Sample XML usage

```
<com.your.package.CustomSwitch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Now the idea is to call the method **setCheckedProgrammatically** in code. **setChecked** gets called by Android when users changes the state of the compund button

Note that I'm using a switch, which extends the compund button, you can use basically the same code on any other (checkbox, ...)

Answer (score 2):

For kotlin use this extension:

```kotlin
fun CompoundButton.setOnUserCheckedChangeListener(callback: (isChecked: Boolean) -> Unit) {
    setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
        if (buttonView.isPressed) {
            callback.invoke(isChecked)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check this link http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#ToggleButton

A simple onChangeListener will do:

```
         public class TestProjectActivity extends Activity {

      ToggleButton one; 
     ToggleButton two;
    ToggleButton three;
     ToggleButton four;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


one = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
two = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton2);
three = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton3);
four = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton4);

one.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
two.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
three.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
four.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeChecker);
      }

      OnCheckedChangeListener changeChecker = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked){
        if (buttonView == one) {
            two.setChecked(false);
            three.setChecked(false);
            four.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (buttonView == two) {
            one.setChecked(false);
            three.setChecked(false);
            four.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (buttonView == three) {
            two.setChecked(false);
            one.setChecked(false);
            four.setChecked(false);
        }
        if (buttonView == four) {
            two.setChecked(false);
            three.setChecked(false);
            one.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **View.OnTouchListener** to listen to detect user interactions.
I implemented this in my adapter class.

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>
implements AccountUtils.OnAccountStateChange ,View.OnTouchListener{

// variable to store whether screen id pressed or not
public static boolean pressed=false;


//If User touches the screen 
//MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN is triggred
//and when user lifts his hand (takes away from screen)
//MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is triggred
// Here you should the change the value of pressed accordingly
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        pressed = true;// Screen Touched
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        pressed = false;// Screen 
        break;
    }
    return false;
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    final SwitchCompat btnToggle;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        btnToggle = (SwitchCompat) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_toggle);
        btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // IF the value in Var pressed is true 
                // only then trigger this event
                if (pressed) {

                    // YOUR METHOD GOES HERE
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Checked Changed",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9130007/2708288

Briefly, use "**boolean CheckBox#isShown()**" to determine which case, it returns false even you modify the check state within onStart() or onResume() of an activity. (I haven't tested the Fragment scenario.)