# android CheckBox how to deferentiate between user click and setChecked

Tags: android, checkbox

I use a checkbox in my app as a button turn something on or off.  But the action (load a file from the network) is done in an async task so I don't want the check to come on until the async task finishes successfully, like this

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if(result==null) {
                return;
            }
            // loaded ok, turn on check mark
            MainActivity.mMp3Cb.setChecked(true);
```

The problem is, `setChecked(true)` causes `OnCheckedChangeListener` to fire again as if it were user input

Is there a way to avoid this? or at least detect it in `onCheckedChanged`?

thanks

Comment: follow this link it will resolve ur problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129858/how-can-i-distinguish-whether-value-is-changed-by-user-or-programmatically-incl

Comment: I am guessing you're executing a task each time user turns on the checkbox. At the top of my head, I'd say use a flag to differentiate between user action and the time you set the state of the checkbox.

Comment: thanks steveoo, that worked great,  now i check isPressed() at start of onCheckedChanged and if false, i know it wasn't user click. why didn't you make it an answer?

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `isPressed()` method of the button view object. Here's an example of a toggle button in Android. `buttonView.isPressed()` is only true if the user clicked on the button.

```
@Override
public synchronized void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
        // human input  
    } else {
        // result of setChecked(boolean)
    }
}
```