# FireBase TIMESTAMP undesirably updates

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

My idea is to allow a user add things in his userlist. When user clicks checkbox, it creates an item with data in FireBase database (I want to sort the user list in the future by the time).

[image]
[image]

I do so by the following code:

```js
favCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    //Add item
                    favMap.put("comicsId", comicsId);
                    favMap.put("comicsGenreId", comicsGenreId);
                    favMap.put("comicsTitle", comicsTitle);
                    favMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                    favListRef.setValue(favMap);
                }
                if(!b){
                    //Remove item
                    favListRef.removeValue();
                }
            }
        });
```

And to make checkBox be checked (if user has already added item before) I use the code:

```js
//Check if already added
        favListRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(dataSnapshot1.getValue() != null && !dataSnapshot1.getValue().equals("")){
                        //Item already added set as checked
                        favCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
```

So everything is fine except for every time when the "checker" code finds out that an item has already added it sets the checkbox as checked and then time in database updates (that ruins my idea of sorting by time).

How can I implement the "TIMESTEAMP" idea with FireBase database and not update time after every check?

Would like to see your answers and pieces of advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use click listener for checkbox rather than oncheck changed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307643/2711811 .  These means the firebase callback sets it as checked but only when user physically clicks does the button callback get called.  There's also another answer there which uses the "isPressed" selector on the compound button using the onCheckedChanged - again to distinguish between user and code setting checkbox.

Comment: Thank you so much. I made it by handling it by onClickListener and a bit of boolean and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andy.

To handle the issue I made items adding and removing by ***onClickListener*** :

```java
boolean checkBoxChecked;
...
//ClickListener
        favCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(checkBoxChecked){
                    //Remove item
                    favListRef.removeValue();
                    checkBoxChecked = !favCheckBox.isChecked();//false
                }
                if(!checkBoxChecked){
                    //Add item
                    favMap.put("comicsId", comicsId);
                    favMap.put("comicsGenreId", comicsGenreId);
                    favMap.put("comicsTitle", comicsTitle);
                    favMap.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                    favListRef.setValue(favMap);
                    checkBoxChecked = favCheckBox.isChecked();//true
                }
            }
        });

        //Check if user already added item
        favListRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(dataSnapshot1.getValue() != null && !dataSnapshot1.getValue().equals("")){
                        //Item was added
                        favCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                        checkBoxChecked = favCheckBox.isChecked();//true
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
```

TIMESTAMP changes only when user clicks on checkBox.

Comment: Glad it helped - and actually you wouldn't need the boolean since you could cast `view` in the `onClick(View view)` callback  to a `CompoundButton` and use its `isChecked` - since you know its a checkbox (which is a CompoundButton).  Btw - your posts include `<!-- language: lang-js -->` which is not correct - it is java - so the snippet stuff doesn't work.