# Android togglebutton change state

Tags: java, android, togglebutton

this is my code:

```
tglSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
             int  t= isChecked ? 1 : 0;                  
             Log.i("t",t);
    }
}
```

when the user check or uncheck the togglebutton , the above code will run, and when i use this code too.

```
tglSwitch.setChecked(true);
```

how can i detect OnCheckedChangeListener() only when user do it?

Comment: You can take a look to the 2nd answer, but it's not very nice :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187287/how-to-know-whether-user-has-changed-the-state-of-toggle-button

Comment: @Bubu thanks but it's not corrent answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of it with a separate variable

```
int userChecked = 0;
int checked = 0;
tglSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new  OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
         int  userChecked= isChecked ? 1 : 0;
         int checked= isChecked? 1:0;    
         Log.i("t",userchecked);
    }
}


if(userChecked == 0){
       tglSwitch.setChecked(true);
       checked = 1;} 
else {
      userChecked = 0;
      tglSwitch.setChecked(true);
      checked = 1;
}
```

That way you can determine who actually checked the variable (system or not).  You could also set the variable to one variable and use it -1 for system changed or 1 for user changed.